# Different Searchable configuration for each fragment (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawerlayout, android-search, searchactivity

I have an Activity (MainActivity) with a Navigation Drawer, and i change the main container with the appropriete Fragment every  time a section (lets say i have tow: Tags and channels) is selected. I want to add a custom **Search activity** for each fragement, can i do that ?

I already did that with one fragment but the default searchable configuration is attached to the activity not the fragment. So how can i set a **different** Searchable Configuration to every fragement i have?

**.MainActivity**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".TagSearchActivity" />

    </activity>
```

**My Search Activities**

```
     <activity android:name=".TagSearchActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable_tag"/>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".model.ChannelSearchActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable_channel"/>
    </activity>
```

To get the search service from the fragment i use this code

```
 SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_tag);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
```

Comment: Use sethasOptionMenu(true) in every Fragment.  Now In fragment override OncreateOptionMenu() method and  searchView initialize and code your logic.

Comment: yeh @Divyesh i did that and it's working, but i don't know how to set the search activity that should be launched using the search manager

Comment: Add Search Menu item in toolbar